# cd digital out to usb

Tags: usb

Is there a product that allows the "coaxial" digital out (or the optical toslink) from a cd player to be send to a usb or firewire port?  I'm not looking for a DAC, I'm looking for digital to digital.

Answer (score 2):

There is! Generically this is called an [audio interface](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/2647/95). These most commonly include ADCs/DACs and analog preamps, but an audio interface with a digital input (such as S/PDIF or optical TOSLink) will give you the "digital to digital" connectivity you're looking for.